# angular $http post with json data- not working at safari

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send json data to my controller using $http post. 
now, in all browsers everything goes well, but in safari, from some reason, I cannot send any json data to my controller.
if I send request and get back json, everything is ok. the problem occurs only in sending data. I tried already all I found, nothing helps.

this is sending code :

```
return $http({
            url: '/Data/SetNewUser',
            method: 'POST',           
            data: JSON.stringify({ _item: _newUser }),
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
        });
```

please help

Comment: browser version? (not just a browser settings problem...?)

Comment: what is the signature of your service that you're calling?

Comment: if i put alert before that print the JSON.stringify({ _item: _newUser }) it works like magic